# Cut, paste, delete and shift

Tags: excel, vba

I have one column in Excel which contains data:
Let say : A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6 ...A100

I want to make a macro which can Cut, paste and delete shift like this:
A1 stays
A2 -> B1
A3 -> C1.
Delete A2, A3 and shift.

When we shift:
A2 then stays
A3 -> B1
A4 -> C1
Delete A3, A4 and shift and so one.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a macro with a for loop.

For example:

```
For i = 1 To 100
    Cells(1, i).Value = Cells(i, 1)
    Cells(1, i).Value = ""
Next i
```